# No sound output devices listed on Debian testing

Tags: linux, audio, debian

After I installed some updates form the package manager my sound device is missing on Debian testing:

```
$ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: Hera Kernel: 5.18.0-2-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME
    v: 42.2 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 13 9343 v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Dell model: 0TM99H v: A00 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell
    v: A15 date: 01/23/2018
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.18.0-2-amd64 running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.52 running: yes
```

[image]

PipeWire and Alsa seem to be up and running.

I tried this solution without any result: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04

Any ideas how to debug/fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. I was trying different linux-headers / linux-image packages but the problem still persists with:

- linux-image-5.18.0-2-amd64
- linux-image-6.0.0-6-amd64
- linux-image-6.1.0-1-amd64

I think that the reason is that recently debian moved from pulseaudio to pipewire, probably,

```
apt install pipewire-pulse wireplumber
```

can solve the problem.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/y2bqjx/comment/is56t5g/?context=3